# CSS add more properties to class

Tags: css

This might be a noob question, but I'm trying to search by terms like "CSS add more propertiers to existent class"; "Add CSS properties to class"; etc and I can't find what I'm looking for.

Imagine I have this:

```
.ui-bar { color: red }
```

Now I want to extend this property, **but continue with the same color red**.

```
.ui-bar-margin { margin-top: 10px; }
```

How can I accomplish this? If you want, you can point me links or terms to search for.

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried to adapt without success. http://jsfiddle.net/mXjHJ/383/

Comment: Like @AlexK. mentioned, you probably want LESS http://lesscss.org/ or Sass http://sass-lang.com/. CSS itself doesn't allow inheritance like you're looking for.

Comment: Interestingly, though, today I came across this link: "Variables are coming to CSS" http://css-tricks.com/abstraction-in-web-languages-and-variables-and-stuff/

Answer (score 0):

You just do it like this... Here's a lot of examples.

```
.ui-bar {
    color: red;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: white;
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. See my answer above.